# Is there something like Promises or Tasks in D?

Tags: promise, d

I am looking for a way to use promises, like the ones in JavaScript or ES5.

I would like to do something like:

```d
auto p = new Promise!string();
webRequest.get("server.com/file.json").then((v) {
    auto json = ParseData(v);
    auto fileContent = fileIO.readFile(json.filename).then((v2) {
        p.resolve(v2);
    });
});
```

Does D have any way to do something like that?

Comment: Small note: `v => {}` [doesn't do what you expect](https://forum.dlang.org/post/thgyqyarccinzuqhcjtf@forum.dlang.org).

Comment: Not an answer, but D has support for Fibers, which are IMO a lot better than promises. Check out vibe.d for an example.

Comment: I was checking that, but I still do not have the right insight about how Fibers can replace the promises. Can you give me an example?

Comment: While this is for node.js it still answers the difference between the two https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-primary-differences-between-Fibers-Futures-and-Promises-in-Node-js excuse me I'm on phone so can't really type up an answer or anything properly.

Comment: Other than that the Phobos documentation is pretty explanatory https://dlang.org/library/core/thread/fiber.html

Comment: I meant: I understand what Fibers are and how work, but I dont realize how to use in a effective way that allows to replace promises.

Comment: @JairoAndresVelascoRomero Some framework (The most prominent D example being Vibe.D) creates a fiber using a function you provide as the body. The framework's asynchronous functions will yield the fiber with an event object describing the task to wait for. Execution resumes to the framework, which then processes the event and eventually resumes the fiber when the task is complete.

Comment: The primary benefit of fibers over callback-based methods like raw callbacks or promises is transparency: the code does not need to be structured to use callbacks/promises, you simply need to (directly or indirectly via a framework function) yield the fiber at whatever point you need to wait for an asynchronous operation to complete. This also means that all flow-control features, such as loops and exceptions, work without needing special handling (ex. creating and returning promises, setting up failure callbacks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://vibed.org/api/vibe.core.concurrency/Future

```
import vibe.core.concurrency : async;
import vibe.inet.urltransfer : download;
import vibe.data.json : parseJsonString;
import vibe.core.file : readFileUTF8;

auto p = async({
    auto content = download("server.com", "file.json");
    auto json = parseJsonString(content);
    auto file_content = readFileUTF8(json["filename"]);
});

auto content = p.getResult();
```

But usage of `async` is actually not needed here as all I/O functions of vibe.d are already 100% asynchronous without any need for callbacks.